# Scala - val a: AnyVal = true, but a.getClass is still Boolean?

Tags: scala

I'm a little bit confused by getClass function:

```
val a: AnyVal = true
```

but a.getClass is Boolean, why not just AnyVal?

Comment: https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass` returns the runtime type backing the value. Just because you've specified/relaxed the type of the value holding the `true` doesn't change the fact that it's backed by a `Boolean`.